# How do I write the required totalCost method?

Tags: java, methods

I have a college assignment to do a program. I am writing in java.  I have completed it pretty much except for one step which is using a `totalCost()` method in order to calculate the total cost of a product from an ordering system.

```
private static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double salesTaxRate)
```

this is the totalCost() method I have to use and this is the code I have so far.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author john
 */
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public class EdenOfGamingPhase1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare variables
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, nameOutputMsg, 
               returnInputMsg, customerReturn, returnOutputMsg, 
               greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg, colorInputMsg, customerColor, colorOutputMsg, featureInputMsg, featureSelection, featureOutputMsg, productAmt, productInputMsg, productOutputMsg, totalPriceAmt;

        // display opening message
        openingMsg = "*** Welcome to the Eden of Gaming Online Ordering System ***\n"
                   + "                     Thank you for choosing the Nosy Entertainment Station 4 !";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);

        // get required input using dialogs
        nameInputMsg   = "Please enter your name: ";
        customerName   = getstringInput(nameInputMsg);
        returnInputMsg = "Are you a returning customer (yes or no)? ";
        customerReturn = getstringInput(returnInputMsg);
        colorInputMsg = "Please enter what color you would like you product to be (red,blue,green,etc).";
        customerColor = getstringInput(colorInputMsg);
        featureInputMsg = "Please select which system model you would like (Brownray or Internet";
        featureSelection = getstringInput(featureInputMsg);
        productInputMsg = "Please select how many systems you wish to order.";
        productAmt = getstringInput(productInputMsg);


        // build output strings
        nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
        returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n\n";
        colorOutputMsg = "Your Nosy Entertainment Station 4 is color " + customerColor + ".\n";
        featureOutputMsg ="You have selected the system model. " + featureSelection + ".\n";
        productOutputMsg = "You have chosen number of systems " + productAmt + ".\n";
        totalPriceAmt ="The total cost for your product is $. " + "\n";
        greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for shopping at The Eden of Gaming!" + "\n\n"
                          + "You should be transferred to the checkout screen in less than 10 seconds.\n";

        // create and display output string
        outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + colorOutputMsg + featureOutputMsg + productOutputMsg + totalPriceAmt + greetingOutputMsg;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMsg);

        System.exit(0);
    } // end main()

    private static String getstringInput(String prompt){
        int count = 0;
        String input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( prompt );
        while ((input != null  && input.length() == 0) && (count <2)){
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error: You must make a selection. \n" + prompt);
            count++;
        }
        if (count==2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "We did not recieve a selection please try again to complete your order. PROGRAM TERMINATED.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return input;

    }
} // end class PizzasRUsPhase1
```

I am just unsure where to begin the `totalCost()` method or even how to use it.

Comment: After you receive selection from User ?

Comment: Where is your method ? In which class ? Note: put your process in a class and call it from the main method to use OO coding!

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what the assignment was. As it is, your program merely receives input and displays it, it doesn't have much actual logic.

Comment: here is the actual assignment

Comment: 4. Create a method called totalCost( ) that calculates the total cost of an order. Use the following header:

    private static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double salesTaxRate)

Number is the number of items (the quantity), cost is the unit cost (the cost of a single item), and salesTax is the sales tax rate. You should select a reasonable value for the unit cost (e.g., $10.00). You should select a reasonable value for the sales tax rate (e.g., 7%). Use your totalCost( ) method to calculate the total cost of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly your trying to do, but basically you should use objects to do this. give the objects (product that user can buy) a price, something like this maybe:

```
public class Product(){
    public Product(int price, String name){ 
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }    
}
```

Then you could have a getPrice() class:

```
public int getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}
```

which you could call to calculate the price, something like this:

```
int totalCost = product1.getPrice() + product2.getPrice() ...;
```

or if you have all the product in a list:

```
int totalCost = 0;
for (Product product : productList){
    totalCost += product.getPrice();
}
```

these are just simple ideas since I don't know what exactly your supposed to do...